# How to make Badge in navbar located in _Layout.cshtml receive value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

How to make the Badge that is in the navbar that is in the _Layout.cshtml capture in all the navigation of my application information of my ControllerWarnings?

In my ControllerWarning I have a function that when requesited returns a numeric value in Json.

```
namespace VS.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerWarning : Controller
    {
        private VSContext db = new VSContext();

        public JsonResult GetWarning(string user)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
            int contWarning = 0;

            var listaAvisos = db.Warnings.Where(a => a.User== user).ToList();
            var l = new List<Aviso>();

            foreach (var item in listaAvisos)
            {
                var res = item.Data - dt;
                item.QtdDias = res.Days;

                if (res.Days <= 5 && item.Enviado != true)
                {
                    contWarning++;
                }
            }

            return Json(contWarning);
        }
      }

      public ActionResult Index(){...}
      public ActionResult Details(int? id){...}
      public ActionResult Details(Warning warning){...}
 }
```

**Navbar located in _Layout.cshtml has a Badge that should collect the GetWarning (string user) return from the WarningController**

```
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Warning", "Index", "Warnings")
         <span class="badge">

                 @*HERE VALUE RECEIVED GETWARNING*@
                 GetWarning(string user)

         </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your action method returns the HTML for your badge, which includes the data(warning number) as well.

```
public class WarningController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Badge()
   {
      int contWarning = 10; // temp hard coded value for demo;
      // Replace the hard coded value 
      // with your existing code to get the data from database
      return PartialView("Badge",contWarning);
   }
}
```

Now in your `Badge.cshtml`, which is storngly typed to `int` type, render the HTML you want.

```
@model int
<span class="badge">
    @Model
</span>
```

Now in your layout(`_Layout.cshtml`), call this render the output of this Badge action method using the `Html.Action` method.

```
 @Html.Action("Badge","Warning")
```

Make sure you are returning a partial view (which does not have it's own layout) using `PartialView` instead of `View` method. If your Badge action method is returning a view which has the same layout file, that will cause an infinite loop and you will get the StackOverflow exception.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: In Error List this is giving the following message:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
D: \ Documents and Settings \ Visual Studio \ Visual Studio 2017 \ Projects \ VolteSempre \ ReturnSempre \ Views \ Notices \ Badge.cshtml 1 Can not convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type

Comment: Are you passing a null to the view from your action method ?